# sonarqube - 500 Internal Server Error - No such file OR directory

Tags: sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

When I go to create a new quality profile, I receive a generic Internal Server Error (500) page.

The trace of my sonar log file is:

```
2015.10.01 15:24:49 ERROR web[rails] /!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Thu Oct 01 15:24:49 +0900 2015
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  No such file or directory - C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp
    org/jruby/RubyFile.java:842:in `stat'
    jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/sonarqube-5.1.2/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/tmpdir.rb:33:in `tmpdir'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
    jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/sonarqube-5.1.2/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/tmpdir.rb:30:in `tmpdir'
    jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/sonarqube-5.1.2/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/tmpdir.rb:109:in `tmpdir'
    jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/sonarqube-5.1.2/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/tmpdir.rb:141:in `create'
    org/jruby/ext/tempfile/Tempfile.java:88:in `initialize'
    org/jruby/RubyIO.java:852:in `new'
    C:/Program Files/Java/sonarqube-5.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/utils.rb:559:in `parse_multipart'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1519:in `loop'
    C:/Program Files/Java/sonarqube-5.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/utils.rb:537:in `parse_multipart'
    C:/Program Files/Java/sonarqube-5.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/request.rb:268:in `parse_multipart'
    C:/Program Files/Java/sonarqube-5.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/request.rb:146:in `POST'
    C:/Program Files/Java/sonarqube-5.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:15:in `call'
    C:/Program Files/Java/sonarqube-5.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
    file:/C:/Program Files/Java/sonarqube-5.1.2/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in `context'
    C:/Program Files/Java/sonarqube-5.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:58:in `call'
    C:/Program Files/Java/sonarqube-5.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
    C:/Program Files/Java/sonarqube-5.1.2/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
    file:/C:/Program Files/Java/sonarqube-5.1.2/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in `serve_rails'
    file:/C:/Program Files/Java/sonarqube-5.1.2/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in `call'
    file:/C:/Program Files/Java/sonarqube-5.1.2/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in `call'
```

sonarqube-5.1.2 and sonar-runner-2.4

In eclipse pugin there is no problem. But with sonar-runner above problem happened...
I can't find effectie answer on the internet. So, please :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/4-1-Internal-Server-Error-when-creating-new-Quality-Profile-td5022730.html)

Just add in `<SONAR>/conf/wrapper.conf` another directory temp with all access with the properties :

```
set.TMPDIR=/path/to/your/temp
```

Then, restart your SonarQube instance.